# django / pass multiple models to my ListView

Tags: python, django, listview, django-models

It's my first project and I'm trying to pass multiple models to my ListView and get them to my template/index via different context_object_names but there seems to be shortcut or another way to do it that I'm missing.

#### models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Kunafa(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    offer = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Baklawa(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    offer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

class Crunchy_kunafa(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    offer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Topping(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

#### views.py

```py
from .models import Kunafa, Crunchy_kunafa, Baklawa, Topping
from django.views.generic import ListView

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Kunafa
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Kunafa'

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Baklawa
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Baklawa'

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Crunchy_kunafa
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Crunchy_kunafa'

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Topping
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Topping'
```

#### index/template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}

<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for kun in Kunafa %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ kun.name }}</a></h4>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for bak in Baklava %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ bak.name }}</a></h4>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for crun in Crunchy_kunafa %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ crun.name }}</a></h4>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for top in Topping %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ top.name }}</a></h4>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Any help or advice to resolve it or even clean up my code, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Perhaps your models `Kunafa`, `Baklawa`, etc. all can be **one model**, as looking at their fields it is entirely the same, all you would need is an extra field in the model to indicate which one of these an instance is.

Comment: @Sid Thanks for your help .. I thought about doing that but I need to separate them under different container on my home page and i believe that wouldn't be possible via for loop ! or What do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this first you should call base context and add dictionary to it as context

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Kunafa
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the Baklawa
        context['baklawa'] = Baklawa.objects.all()
        context['crunchy_kunafa'] = Crunchy_kunafa.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your consideration deneil James ! I did type the code as you mentioned above and I get this ... typeError at/ super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type.. may you please explain to me why

Comment: @AyobSaleh please once check updated ans I have edited ans

Comment: I tried to add the last model which is the Topping ! I got nameError (name 'Topping_objects' is not defined) . so I deleted it and the code worked but I only got the Crunchy_kunafa showed on my index page

Comment: Import that model and do same as i did above

Comment: I did import the models and I did as you mentioned to and I got the result that I told you

Comment: It did work now .. Thank you @daneil James

Comment: Accept the ans if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

First off all i believe you have to update your models as they are related and most of fields are repeated.Else if you don't want any update in model then For class based view you have to add extra data to context being passed to template by overriding get_context_data method.

Please check with updated index.html and views.py:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  </head>
  <body>
      
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for kun in Kunafa %}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap">-->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class=""><a href="{{ kun.get_absolute_url }}">{{ kun.name }}</a></h4>
                                <p class="card-text"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for bak in Baklawa %}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap"> -->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ bak.name }}</a></h4>
                                <p class="card-text"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for crun in Crunchy_kunafa %}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap"> -->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ crun.name }}</a></h4>
                                <p class="card-text"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for top in Topping %}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200" alt="card image cap"> -->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class=""><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_url }}">{{ top.name }}</a></h4>
                                <p class="card-text"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views.py:**
from .models import Kunafa, Crunchy_kunafa, Baklawa, Topping
from django.views.generic import ListView

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Kunafa
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Kunafa'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['Baklawa'] = Baklawa.objects.all()
         context['Crunchy_kunafa'] = Crunchy_kunafa.objects.all()
         context['Topping'] = Topping.objects.all()
         return context

# class HomeView(ListView):
#     model = Baklawa
#     template_name = 'index.html'
#     context_object_name = 'Baklawa'

# class HomeView(ListView):
#     model = Crunchy_kunafa
#     template_name = 'index.html'
#     context_object_name = 'Crunchy_kunafa'

# class HomeView(ListView):
#     model = Topping
#     template_name = 'index.html'
#     context_object_name = 'Topping'
```

**If you want to go with the same models with function based views its pretty simple as below:**

```
def home_view(request):
    Kunafa_list = Kunafa.objects.all()
    Baklawa_list = Baklawa.objects.all()
    Crunchy_kunafa_list = Crunchy_kunafa.objects.all()
    Topping_list = Topping.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'Kunafa_list':Kunafa_list,'Baklawa_list':Baklawa_list,'Crunchy_kunafa_list':Crunchy_kunafa,'Topping_list':Topping_list})
```

Comment: I was actually doing it similar to this way but i thought they'd be another way to do it with ListView, to clean up the code little bit and learn about it more as ... but thank so much for your help @ashish nautiyal

Comment: It did work now .. Thank you @ashish nautiyal